# How to correctly add documentation in my c# code (similar to javadoc)

Tags: c#, documentation-generation

Is there any native way of documenting my code in C#? Something similar to javadoc in java and different of doxygen or Sandcastle.

Comment: I use [GhostDoc](https://submain.com/products/ghostdoc.aspx), they have a free version, but it's well worth the couple bucks to buy it.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You might benefit from using "guided mode" next time you ask a question, to help ensure you include the right details to get a better answer.

Comment: @RonBeyer, muti thanks for the comment, I'll analyze the tool!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not familiar with JavaDoc, but you can type `///` above classes and methods in Visual Studio to generate summary code blocks. Further you can enable XML documentation in your project properties so that summary data is included in class libraries, Swagger auto-generated API documentation, etc.